# Array modifier make unwanted offset

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to array this object on Y-axis *only*.

[image]

I make Y offset 1.00 and both X,Z are Zero.

But when I do that it shows an offset in x-axis so both end circle are not match each other like the one in the image above.

[image]

[image]

I also apply scale and rotation but it still the same.

Comment: Hello :). There's no actual offset. Your geometry is tilted, so it doesn't align. Correct the tilt and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Where is the "offset" coming from? It is built in as part of object, the mesh is not aligned in the $X$ axis. The array modifier will only repeat that offset as well.

There are two basic options:

1. Rotate the object in edit mode so that the object is aligned on the $X$ axis

[image]

2. In the Relative offset parameters of the array modifier, play with the values on for the $X$ and $Y$ axis until the objects align. Note that by doing that the object will still not line up to the $Y$ Axis. But maybe that is what you want? I don't know.

[image]